# Add element to a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I want to add an element (child, div) to a mother-div, that already has one or more children. I made a script for this action but when I execute the script I am not able to manipulate style attributes afterwards. So I assume I did something wrong in my creation-script. I also added a console message (end of the script) and that also indicates there are no style attributes filled in at the new div. So, please could someone indicate what the reason is...

As I am quite new to javascript I assume the reason is quite simple. But although I checked many other questions and solutions, I do not get the proper solution for my issue. I think it should be in appendChild or insertBefore.

```js
function preparevideo(videonaam, titel) {
  // add a div to the video-div
  const nieuwetitel = document.createElement("div");
  // give the new div an id so it will be unique
  nieuwetitel.id = videonaam + '-id';
  // give the div a class for the markup
  nieuwetitel.className = 'page-roel-video-titel';
  // create the text in the div
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(titel);
  // add the textnode to the div
  nieuwetitel.appendChild(textnode);
  // find the element where the new div should be added to  
  let videomodule = document.getElementById(videonaam);
  // and finally add the new div to the video-div, as the first child
  videomodule.insertBefore(nieuwetitel, videomodule.children[0]);

  console.log('-------after adding div------');
  console.log('-------complete style of titleblock------');
  console.log(document.getElementById(videonaam + '-id').style);
  console.log('prepare video afgerond');
}
preparevideo("naam1","Eerste video");
```

```html
<div id="naam1"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please show a [mcve] that highlights the issue and the expected result - I do not see where you modify any style

Comment: I would personally use  `nieuwetitel.classList.add('page-roel-video-titel');`  instead of className

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't set any style attribute before console.log that's why you didn't get any result. After implementing some style, you can log the the style. Then you will see the difference.
Here I added some style before the console.log

```js
function preparevideo(videonaam, titel) {
  // add a div to the video-div
  const nieuwetitel = document.createElement("div");
  // give the new div an id so it will be unique
  nieuwetitel.id = videonaam + '-id';
  // give the div a class for the markup
  nieuwetitel.className = 'page-roel-video-titel';
  // create the text in the div
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(titel);
  // add the textnode to the div
  nieuwetitel.appendChild(textnode);
  // find the element where the new div should be added to  
  let videomodule = document.getElementById(videonaam);
  // and finally add the new div to the video-div, as the first child
  videomodule.insertBefore(nieuwetitel, videomodule.children[0]);

  // Applying style
  document.getElementById(videonaam + '-id').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  document.getElementById(videonaam + '-id').style.color = 'white'

  console.log('-------after adding div------');
  console.log('-------complete style of titleblock------');
  console.log(document.getElementById(videonaam + '-id').style);
  console.log('prepare video afgerond');
}
preparevideo("naam1","Eerste video");
```

```html
<div id="naam1"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You already gave it a class, you can target it in your css and added the needed styles

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I'm slowly climbing up there --- I'd soon be able to post comments, but for now...

Comment: @rehkmansa there's no *for now*. A comment is **not** an **Answer** (eligible for votes and acceptance).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that there is no unique `id` value for `nieuwetitel` element generated. When you use `getElementById()` method you get only first element from DOM.

Comment: Since the `id` gets set by a parameter called `videonaam`, how do you see whether it is not unique?

Comment: `videonaam` parameter is used to define parent node as well, so all added to this parent node children will have the same `id`.

Comment: None prevents him from making a `naam2`. Atleast that is what the ordinal suggests.

Comment: @Lain Which do you mean? I don't see that code generates unique id.

Comment: In the code given the generated `id` is unique. The rest is a speculation on how the function gets called. Since `naam1` contains an ordinal it could as well be `preparevideo("naam1","xxx"); preparevideo("naam2","xxx");`.

Comment: Yes, but the comments in code says: 
  // and finally add the new div to the video-div, as the first child
  videomodule.insertBefore(nieuwetitel, videomodule.children[0]); Of cause if there is a parent for each it will be unique.

Comment: Sorry: the videonaam is unique! Not enforced by application but I am sure it is